# Best practice for android dynamically load Listview at scroll end?

Tags: android, mysql

I have been working on an android project that has a feed similar to Instagram/Facebook and I am trying to figure out the best strategy for consuming the data from my database.

Specifically I am wondering if I should query all the data at once (assume 50 records +) or if should I perform queries as the user scrolls -- grabbing so many records at a time. If the ladder, about how many posts/records should I get per query assuming the content/size is similar to that of a Facebook post.

I've spent a descent amount of time researching this issue and haven't come across anything so any suggestions would be much appreciated. I do apologize if this issue has already been addressed and if you could you just post the location of the answer that'll work too.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: add pagination concept first. Fetch 10 elements at at time. When user reaches at end of list then fetch 10 more records.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching all the data can be too much at times and your app will have very slow response time, that why it's better to load some data at a time and just add it as you get it. In my opinion it's best to load 2 screens of data at a time, so try and see how many posts you can have in a screen and get x2 (if on one time you can see 5 posts, load 10 at a time) or load for example 10 at the first time and 5 each next time. This truly is your preference as I think.

If this is the method you want to use keep in mind that there are different screen sizes for android (from android wear to different sized mobile phones, tablets and smart tv-s) so try making different methods for each group if devices. You can maybe have an abstract class (or interface) with the method and have every other class for different size extend or implement (regarding of using class or interface) to make the code more well written, easier to change and reusable.

But all in all it's in your hands and you can make it by your liking. Hope this helps, and gives you some matter to wrap your head around.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Just one follow-up question; say it was 10 and I wanted to create a "smooth" scroll experience, should I not wait till the user gets to the last post and instead maybe start to load the next 10 when the user gets about halfway (5th or 6th post)? @Dana

Comment: Yes, you are right I haven't exactly thought of that case, for smoothness sake maybe it's better to load it in time. You should research more about scroll animation there are many types, so you can find the one who fits your needs and maybe then try with different values until you find the one that's right for you and for your UX. Keep in mind that everyone has a different type of connection, and put some loading bar if the user scrolls too fast. 
If my input was informing and helped you please up vote it (this is a good practice and, we who answer get reputation points as well).

Comment: I did up vote it, but because I don't have enough rep points it doesn't show publicly. Thanks again!! @Dana